# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'viewConfig.Manager')

Tags: react-native, expo

Im trying to upgrade expo sdk from version 33 to 34 and getting undefined is not an object (evaluating 'viewConfig.Manager') inside react-native package

package.json

```
"date-fns": "^2.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.7.0",
    "expo": "^34.0.1",
    "expo-analytics-amplitude": "~5.0.1",
    "expo-asset": "^5.0.1",
    "expo-constants": "^6.0.0",
    "expo-font": "~5.0.1",
    "expo-intent-launcher": "^6.0.0",
    "expo-keep-awake": "~5.0.1",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~5.0.1",
    "expo-localization": "~5.0.1",
    "expo-location": "^5.0.1",
    "expo-permissions": "^6.0.0",
    "expo-yarn-workspaces": "^1.1.0",
    "i18n-js": "3.2.2",
    "pomeranian-durations": "^1.8.1",
    "prop-types": "15.7.2",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-34.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-app-intro-slider": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "0.9.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-spacer": "^0.4.1",
    "react-navigation": "^3.9.1",
    "react-redux": "6.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "2.13.8",
    "redux-logger": "3.0.6",
    "redux-optimist": "^1.0.0",
    "redux-sentry-middleware": "^0.1.1",
    "redux-persist": "6.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "2.3.0",
    "sentry-expo": "2.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^4.2.0",
    "synced-interval": "^0.2.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same issue for the last two hours.

In my case there were some outdated libraries (including one I authored) using the old version of react-native which somehow causes this error.

Try running:

```
npm outdated
```

And then install new versions of outdated libraries listed using expo-cli one by one.

Hope this helps :)